# I can't texture paint due to "missing uv, textures!" error

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to paint this
[image: image 1]

But every time it errors and brings up
[image: image 2]

I can paint the picture on the left but it does not affect the object, and I cannot paint the object directly.
[image: image 3]

These are my shader node settings.
[image: image 4]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The warning gives you already a hint what is missing. Go to UV Editing layout, and add UV mapping to this object. - I would also suggest to embedd the images into the post.

Comment: Please don't use external links for images. You can simply put them directly into the question.